# Can I install a fence post immediately adjacent to an existing one?

Tags: fence

I want to install a new all-wooden fence across the far end of my garden. Ideally, with my neighbour's permission, I would have attached the far left panel to the last post of their end fence which sits on our shared boundary. Unfortunately that fence is collapsing under the weight of massively overgrown ivy, and the post is being pulled over towards their property, and is completely unsuitable for me to make use of. I don't think waiting for them to repair or replace their fence is an option, so I need to install my own end post adjacent to the existing one. I obviously want to put it as close as possible to minimise any gap, especially as the lean of the existing post makes a triangular gap unavoidable and I don't want to make it any bigger.

I was planning to use concrete groundings for my new posts but it seems that, for this post, given that the existing toppling-over post is grounded in a post spike, that the best chance of success without affecting the existing post is to bang in another post spike right next to it.

So my question is: is it wise to fix a post right up against the base of an existing one? Or is it always better to try to either put it further away or try to utilise the existing post?

Comment: put the post a short distance away ... install a narrow panel between the two posts that is attached only to one post

Comment: @jsotola Thanks - that's actually what my workmen did in the end.